# Cross Domain communication security from APP to PHP server

Tags: security, cross-domain

I have written an app with Phonegap which can be used by multible users.  The app itself have to communicate with the same server.

So there are many users connection to the same server, however there is a problem, the security between the clients and the server, is atm "plain text".

I believe its called Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

I am not sure how to make the connection between all those clients and the server secure.

**What i want to achieve is**

Make the data encrypted, so that no one can easily sniff the data.

**My idea so far is**

Use ex. sha1/md5 or a selfwritten encryption algoritm, with some SALT added and maybe an extra key.  Implement that encryption algoritm on both the clients and the server, and encrypt/decrypt on the fly.

I have already added a PHP line to get it to work, but that dosent make it secure:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

I would like some advise on my thoughts, would my idea work, or is something else required?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel :) Simply use HTTPS to encrypt all your HTTP data.

Comment: Good idea, i never tried that before.  could u give me a hint or two on how to process to step 1 2 and 3? :)

Comment: I am going to stick with this.  I found a really good guide for it.  Thanks for turning my mind in the right direction :)

Comment: Np. I didn't have time to explain before, but now I have: CORS is a way for the browser to allowing/disallow Ajax requests that originate from browsers from domains other than its own. It is an authorization protocol, while HTTPS is a secure channel protocol. The two can work together.